# Character points in a simple RPG stats program

Tags: python

What I'm trying to figure out here, is how to add a limited number of character points for these rpg "stats". Ex: if you have 10 character points, and add 2 to one of the stats, you'll have 8 character points left. How would I do this?

```
class Stats:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stat = 5

    def add(self, amount):
        self.stat += amount
        return self.stat

    def sub(self, amount):
        self.stat -= amount
        return self.stat

st = Stats()
ch = Stats()
ag = Stats()
```

Comment: Assuming you have a `Player` class, you could have an attribute in there for remaining points. When the user skills up a stat you make sure there are enough remaining points, and if so, make the change. You could change that attribute whenever the player levels up.

Comment: @RussellBarlet I am not sure if this is what you want that is why i am posting it in comments:

`class test:
    stat = 10

class Stats(test):

    def add(self, amount):
        test.stat -= amount
        return test.stat

    def sub(self, amount):
        test.stat += amount
        return test.stat

    def dis(self):
        print test.stat

st = Stats()
st.dis() # 10
st.add(2)
st.dis() # 8
ch = Stats()
ch.sub(1)
ch.dis() # 9
ag = Stats()
ag.add(3)
ag.dis() # 6`

please notify me if that is what you want.